# Adding An Extra Tab When Configuring/Creating An Event

Tags: civievent, forms, gsoc

I want to add a new tab called "Web Tracking" when creating a New Event.
I want to do this so that I can keep all the parameters for web tracking separate from the other Event parameters. How do I go about this?

The only relevant file I could find is civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/ManageEvent/TabHeader.php

I have attached a picture in case the description is not clear.
(I got the picture from the CiviCRM forum)[image: Tab]

Comment: Can you clarify which version of CiviCRM you are targeting? The screenshot appears to be from an older version of Civi, but my recommendation would be to write extensions using 4.6, the current version.

Answer (score 9):

I see now that you are working on core code. But just for the record, if you were doing this in an extension you would proceed by implementing [hook_civicrm_tabset](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_tabset).

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out with the help of my mentor Kurund Jalmi.

Make changes to the following files:

1) civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/ManageEvent/TabHeader.tpl

2) civicrm/CRM/Event/xml/Menu/Event.xml

3) Do a menu rebuild

4) Create the corresponding php and template files

Comment: Unless you are coding for core tpl overrides are really a last resort - so if you aren't doing a core submission Coleman's recommendation is better (assuming it works)